# At the Unix prompt, how do you pull a variable number of lines (which may include a blank line) from a file matching a pattern?

Tags: unix, grep, aix

My file has multiple messages in it, each with a time stamp. I need to pull out just one message from a file based on its timestamp. Sometimes a message will have a blank line within the contents of the message. I prefer to do this at the unix prompt on an AIX operating system.

My file (er96aa.example) contains the following information. I want to pull out the second message with a time stamp of 15:56:10.097 (it should be a total of 4 lines of data).

```
07/05/19 15:56:10.091 SOCKETSND MESSAGE LENGTH=338   MESSAGE:
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

07/05/19 15:56:10.097 SOCKETSND MESSAGE LENGTH=338   MESSAGE:

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

07/05/19 15:56:10.099 SOCKETSND MESSAGE LENGTH=338   MESSAGE:
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I tried

```
  grep -p '15:56:10.097' er96aa.example
```

but that only returns the first two lines.

I tried

```
  grep -p'07/05/19' '15:56:10.097' er96aa.example
```

but that returns nothing.

```
  grep -p'07/05/19'+ '15:56:10.097' er96aa.example   and

  grep -p'07/05/19+' '15:56:10.097' er96aa.example
```

but that returns the whole file

I modified my file and put 07/05/19 on a separate line and "grep -p'07/05/19' '15:56:10.097' er96aa.example" did work, but unfortunately I don't have the ability to modify the format of the file I am usually working with.

Expected Output:

```
07/05/19 15:56:10.097 SOCKETSND
MESSAGE LENGTH=338   MESSAGE:

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have access to an AIX box to test this but try:

```
$ awk '/MESSAGE:/{f=0} /15:56:10.097/{f=1} f' file
07/05/19 15:56:10.097 SOCKETSND MESSAGE LENGTH=338   MESSAGE:

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

#### How it works

By default, awk reads through a file one line at a time.  Our script uses a single variable `f` to determine if the current line should be printed.

- `/MESSAGE:/{f=0}`

  This sets variable `f` to false (`0`) if the regex `MESSAGE:` appears on the current line.
- `/15:56:10.097/{f=1}`

  This sets variable `f` to true (`1`) is the regex `15:56:10.097` appears on the current line.
- `f`

  If `f` is true, print the line.

Comment: Thank you so much John! That worked perfectly. I especially appreciate you explaining the different parts of the command. This will make my work research much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Some variation of Johns post.

```
awk '/^[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}/{f=0} /^07\/05\/19 15:56:10.097/{f=1} f'
07/05/19 15:56:10.097 SOCKETSND MESSAGE LENGTH=338   MESSAGE:

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

This uses exact date and time as a trigger and gets all line to next line starting with date format.

Comment: Thank you Jotne for your response. This did produce the results I needed as well (after I took out the ^ for the last condition). If you have a moment, would you explain what {2} stands for? I have been using AIX for many years, but I haven't gotten very creative with the command line language.

Comment: @SharonR `{2}` does mean repeat two times. `[0-9]{2}` is the same as `[0-9][0-9]` and `[0-9]{3}` is the same as `[0-9][0-9][0-9]`